# TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "background.png"

Tags: python, tkinter

I've switched over to Python 2.7 (from 3.4) recently, and I'm having trouble reading a .png file with Tkinter Photoimage class. I say:

```
background = "background.png"
photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=background)
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 36, in <module>
    photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=background)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 3323, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 3279, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "background.png"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter error: Couldn't recognize data in image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357090/tkinter-error-couldnt-recognize-data-in-image-file)

Answer (score 0):

```
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(background))
```

Comment: Where should the name `Image` come from, and how does this address the problem?

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of your code?

Answer (score 0):

#pip install pillow

from PIL import ImageTk,Image
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('images/sasuke.png'))

Hope This could help!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).