# Tkinter error: Couldn't recognize data in image file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to put a jpg image to a tkinter canvas. tkinter gives me this error:

> couldn't recognize data in image file

I use the code from the documentation:

```
canv = Canvas(root, width=80, height=80, bg='white')
canv.grid(row=2, column=3)

img = PhotoImage(file="bll.jpg")
canv.create_image(20,20, anchor=NW, image=img)
```

Same thing with png images. Even tried to put an image into a label widget, but got the same error. What's wrong?

I am using Python 3 on Mac. Python file and image are in the same folder.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your code seems right, this is running for me on Windows 7 (Python 3.6):

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

canv = Canvas(root, width=80, height=80, bg='white')
canv.grid(row=2, column=3)

img = PhotoImage(file="bll.jpg")
canv.create_image(20,20, anchor=NW, image=img)

mainloop()
```

resulting in this tkinter GUI:

[image: GUI] with this image as `bll.jpg`: [image]

*(imgur converted it to `bll.png` but this is working for me as well.)*

---

More options:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15803828/5276734) mentions, tkinter is working only with `gif` images. Try using a `.gif` image.
- If this is not working, use `PIL` as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23905585/5276734).

---

**Update:** Solution with `PIL`:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
root = Tk()

canv = Canvas(root, width=80, height=80, bg='white')
canv.grid(row=2, column=3)

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("bll.jpg"))  # PIL solution
canv.create_image(20, 20, anchor=NW, image=img)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 15):

I was getting the same issue. I have windows and Python 3.6. So I found two solutions for this either you use/convert to `.png` image (with the same function you have used):

```py
photo = PhotoImage('xyz.png')
l = Label(image = photo)
l.pack()
```

or  if you want to read `.jpg` file only then use PIL library to read and display an image like this:

```py
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("xyz.jpg"))  
l=Label(image=img)
l.pack()
```

Comment: This helped. Although I would suggest adding window and mainloop() to actually display the image.  

`window = Tk()`  and ending with: `window.mainloop()`

Answer (score 7):

Install PIL/Pillow with:

```
pip install Pillow
```

or:

```
sudo pip install pillow
```

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
import tkinter

image = Image.open('bll.jpg')
image = image.resize((20, 20))
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

canv = Canvas(root, width=80, height=80, bg='white')
canv.grid(row=2, column=3)

img = PhotoImage(file=image)
```

Also using .PNG instead of .JPG is better for Tkinter.

Answer (score 7):

To answer the original question directly: Tkinter does not currently support JPG images, and PNG support is dependent on the system's version of Tcl/Tk - a separate library, written in C, which Python interfaces with through Tkinter (hence the "inter" part). The popular third-party library `pillow` provides a drop-in replacement for the Tkinter `PhotoImage` class, allowing it to support many more image formats.

### Image formats supported by Tkinter

The [Tcl/Tk manual](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/image.html) describes support for two separate image types - [`bitmap`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/bitmap.html) and [`photo`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/photo.html) - described thus:

> A bitmap is an image whose pixels can display either of two colors or be transparent.

> A photo is an image whose pixels can display any color or be transparent. A photo image is stored internally in full color (32 bits per pixel), and is displayed using dithering if necessary.

These are reflected in Tkinter as the `BitmapImage` and `PhotoImage` classes, respectively. **The formats supported by Tkinter will depend slightly on what [version](https://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/choose.html) of Tcl/Tk is installed.** However, starting with 3.10, [a threaded build of Tcl/Tk 8.6 is included with official Python binary releases](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/tkinter.html)

The [Python Tkinter documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) is mainly focused on explaining functionality that Tkinter adds on top of Tcl/Tk. For most things, the user is expected to refer to the Tcl/Tk documentation (or third-party sources; the Python documentation offers a few suggestions) and understand [how the interface works generally](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#understanding-how-tkinter-wraps-tcl-tk).

As [pointed out by Donal Fellows on another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75112734/13629335), Tcl/Tk cannot handle individual memory allocations over about 2GB, which theoretically limits image sizes.

### The [BitmapImage](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L4206) class

Tcl/Tk `bitmap`s are much more limited than `photo`s, so practically speaking, `PhotoImage` will be used much more often. But for completeness: `BitmapImage` supports BMP [(cross-platform)](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/bitmap), XPM (for [pixmap / colored bitmaps](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/bitmap+images+with+2+colors+and+transparency), mainly [on X11](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/pixmap)) and ICO formats (ICO is a special bitmap mostly used for Windows icons).

#### The [PhotoImage](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L4122) class

As explained in the Tcl/Tk documentation, a `photo` can be created from a data string containing the raw image data:

> The string should contain binary data or, for some formats, base64-encoded data (this is currently guaranteed to be supported for PNG and GIF images).

`PhotoImage` supports **GIF**, **PPM** and **PGM** images regardless of Tcl/Tk version.

Tcl/Tk version 8.4 [is required to support transparency](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/14.md). (However, as the 8.3 branch [has not been maintained since 2002](https://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/8.3.html), it is practically guaranteed that a current Python installation with Tkinter support will have transparency support.)

Tcl/Tk version 8.6 [adds support for PNG images](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/244.md). If possible, images will be gamma-corrected:

> In addition, the implementation should... [a]llow application of display gamma (if known) in conjunction with the `gAMA` chunk of imported images, if present, through `-format "png -gamma value"`.

SVG support [is planned](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/507.md) [(with some limitations)](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TkCmd/photo.html#M57) in Tcl/Tk 8.7 ([currently in alpha](https://tcl.tk/software/tcltk/8.7.html)). JPEG support might be included in the future, if copyright concerns can be resolved.

In addition, there are several ways to extend the default library support:

- TCL extensions such as [Img](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Img) and [tclimage](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tclimage)
- Custom handlers written using Tcl's C API: see [TkCreatePhotoImageFormat](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkLib/CrtPhImgFmt.html)
- Python extensions: [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html) supports a variety of formats that can all be converted using the [ImageTk module](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageTk.html)

### Verifying image formats

Many other problems with Tkinter image support asked about on Stack Overflow turn out to be caused by an image that is, quite simply, **not in the format the programmer expected**. Note well that simply renaming a file to have the appropriate suffix *will not help* if Tkinter does not already support the image format. The suffix is just a hint as to what data to expect in a file. (The underlying Tcl/Tk library also allows for specifying a format explicitly, but mainly it is deduced from the suffix and/or the data itself.)

Here are some ways to verify the format of an image:

- Open it with an image-editing program. (Re-saving the image in a specified format is by far the easiest way to *fix* a problem with an unsupported format, anyway, so this is often the most practical approach.)
- Use a command-line tool, such as the `file` command on Linux.
- Programmatically, open the file and inspect the first few bytes, for example using the third-party [filetype](https://pypi.org/project/filetype/) package.
- Simply use exception handling (`try`/`except`) and fall back to a placeholder image if the desired image isn't supported. (This may be necessary anyway in case e.g. the image is corrupted or missing.)

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative solution:

```py
filename = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('imagename.jpeg' ))
background_label = tk.Label(self.root, image=filename)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Python package Pillow worked for me.

Just do pip install pillow.

Then use ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Your image path goes here...")) instead of tkinter.PhotoImage()

Answer (score 0):

```py
# in terminal pip install pillow

from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

a_root = Tk()

# WINDOW SIZING

a_root.geometry("600x400")
a_root.minsize(400, 400)
a_root.maxsize(800, 800)

# for PNG IMG
# photo = PhotoImage(file="mark1.png")
# for JPG IMG

image = Image.open("mark.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

img_label = Label(image=photo)
img_label.pack()

a_root.mainloop()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: those are not Python comments

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. You just have to use a PNG file instead of a jpeg/jpg.
if you dont have a png version you can convert your picture here ---> https://cloudconvert.com/

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

root.geometry("1920x1080")
photo = PhotoImage(file="Akatsuki.png")


label = Label(image=photo)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your version of Tkinter doesn't support jpg.
I fix it by installing python 3.10 which has built-in 8.6.11 Tcl/Tk.
https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/

Answer (score -1):

This error could possibly happen because of `relative file path` or `non-English` characters in filepath. So I made this function which works very good in windows and with any kinds of file paths:

```py
def loadrelimages(relativepath):
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image
    import os
    directory_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, relativepath)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(file_path.replace('\\', "/")))  
    return img
```

For example, load `photo_2021-08-16_18-44-28.jpg` which is at the same directory with this code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import os

def loadrelimages(relativepath):
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image
    import os
    directory_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, relativepath)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(file_path.replace('\\',"/")))  
    return img

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

loadedimage=loadrelimages('photo_2021-08-16_18-44-28.jpg')
canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=loadedimage)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If the problem was related to the file path, the OP would get a different error. The error in the question is not because the file couldn't be found.

Answer (score -2):

Install the OpenCV packages for Python:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Then try this code:

```
import cv2
Img = cv2.imread("xxxxx.png") 
cv2.imwrite("xxxxx.png",img) 
# Your code goes here!
```