# Loading an image from a folder that is in the same folder as the program

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have got my file working on my program. However, I am not sure how to load an image from a file that is in a specific folder. So far is my following code, which only can obtain the image directly in the same folder as the program file itself.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

imagetest = PhotoImage(file="giftest.gif")
canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=imagetest)

root.mainloop()
```

I had found some info on [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IW28o11vJfE) about how to link the file to a specific folder, but it only tells the whole destination. I cannot guarantee that the whole folder destination stuff shown by that video will always work if I move the folder containing the program to a different destination; moving that folder will break the image links in the program.

Is there some way of loading an image from a folder that is in the same folder as the program is? I recall that HTML could do this kind of thing too, but I don't know whether Python could do this either.

Comment: You can try using a relative path like `file="./giftest.gif"`

Comment: The relative path stuff is starting to solve my problem. However, I also need to know how to specify a particular folder relative to my image.

Comment: ***Your answer is here:***<br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357090/tkinter-error-couldnt-recognize-data-in-image-file/68805933#68805933

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the folder in your python file containing the image like `"folder/giftest.gif"`. Here is a sample:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

imagetest = PhotoImage(file="folder/subfolder/giftest.gif")  #python file is not in "folder" but "folder" is in your python file directory
canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=imagetest)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is "folder" the name of the folder the program itself is in? And "subfolder" is the name of the folder's folder?

Comment: Actually, when I tested out the program, it seems that I only need to put in the folder's-folder's name and then the filename to load my image from the folder's folder; trying to put my folder's name and my folder's-folder's name would just give an error.

Comment: @RonZhang Python file is not in the `folder` but `folder` is in the python file directory. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 2):

If the absolute path is not fixed, you can always build the file path in your code.

**This would combine the absolute path of the current directory and the relative path of your file.** As long as the relative location of the image is always the same to the python script, this would always work.

```
import os
directory_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, 'relative_path/file')
```

Note that the *directory_path* is the directory path of your python script.

Comment: Does "relative_path" refer to the folder name?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the confusion, I used relative_path in case it is a nested folder. And remember you do not need a "/" in front of the folder name.

Comment: Is it possible to do this for multiple different files? And how would I adjust it if I have multiple files to be displayed?

Comment: Can you clarify your use case? Are your files scattered in different locations or are they in the same folder say ./images/?