# Python 3.7, tkinter, jpg: couldn't recognize data in image file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I wanted to ask some help regarding tkinter, in python3.
I can't seem to display a jpeg image file in a label using the following code:

```
def changephoto(self):
    self.tmpimgpath = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd())
    self.installimagepath.set(self.tmpimgpath)
    self.selectedpicture = PhotoImage(file=self.installimagepath.get())
    self.PictureLabel.configure(image=self.selectedpicture)
```

It can do png Images just fine, but when I try to load a jpg image, all I i am able to get is the following error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file
```

I went through all similar questions I could find, but they all seem to answer the same thing: "from PIL import ImageTk, Image"
When I try that (  for the moment, I am trying to use pillow, btw ), ImageTk doesn't seem to be available.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use `png` or `gif`

Comment: That is not what I need though... The intention is to have the user select an image taken with his/her cellphone, which are jpeg's by default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter error: Couldn't recognize data in image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357090/tkinter-error-couldnt-recognize-data-in-image-file)

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to install `PIL`: `pip install pillow`.

   If `pip` does not successfully install `pillow`, you might have to try `pip3` or `pip3.7` **(use bash to see which options you have)**
2. You can open your image with `ImageTk`:

   ```
   import os
   import tkinter as tk
   from tkinter import filedialog
   from PIL import ImageTk

   def changephoto():
      root = tk.Tk()
      PictureLabel= tk.Label(root)
      PictureLabel.pack()
      tmpimgpath = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd())
      selectedpicture= ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=tmpimgpath)
      PictureLabel.configure(image=selectedpicture)
   ```

Comment: Ok, I guess I was staring at the same problem for too long, it caused me to no longer see the solution right in front of me. For some reason, importing ImageTk just worked now and the images ( even jpeg's) are now displayed. Thanks you very much, Chuck G. I owe you a beer or 2. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided by Chuck G worked. I can't tell why I initially couldn't import ImageTk, but that ended up to just work.

```
from PIL import ImageTk
```

Answer (score -1):

This error could possibly happen because of `relative file path` or `non-English` characters in filepath ,So i made this function which works very good in windows and with any kinds of file paths :

```
def loadrelimages(relativepath):
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image
    import os
    directory_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, relativepath)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(file_path.replace('\\',"/")))  
    return img
```

for example load `photo_2021-08-16_18-44-28.jpg` which is at the same directory with this code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os

def loadrelimages(relativepath):
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image
    import os
    directory_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, relativepath)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(file_path.replace('\\',"/")))  
    return img
root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()


loadedimage=loadrelimages('photo_2021-08-16_18-44-28.jpg')
canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=loadedimage)

root.mainloop()
```

try this!!!!