# PGM file won't open in tkinter window, "couldn't recognize data in image file"

Tags: python, tkinter, photoimage

I am trying to display a PGM image in Tkinter window, however I keep getting the error of "couldn't recognize data in image file". Is there something wrong with my code??

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import PhotoImage
def browse_file(self):
    path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    if len(path) > 0:
        photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=path)
        cv = tk.Canvas()
        cv.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
        cv.create_image(10, 10, image=photo, anchor='nw')
```

Comment: Are you getting the error in `cv.create_image()` function call, or somewhere else in the code? Have you tried with different image files perhaps the image is corrupt in some way -- try other image formats and see if they work.

Comment: hi, i did try different pgm files,they all say “couldn't recognize data in image file”

Comment: It may be that Tkinker does not support PGM files. This looks like a possible dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357090/tkinter-error-couldnt-recognize-data-in-image-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter error: Couldn't recognize data in image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357090/tkinter-error-couldnt-recognize-data-in-image-file)

Comment: Hi, it's true that tkinter PhotoImage doesn't accept png and jpeg images - it is only meant to read GIF PGM and PPM images. that's why I am confused as to why it is not reading it.