# How can I put an image as a background on tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, background-image

To change things up, I wanted to put blue wallpaper image as my background on my python script. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("")
root.iconbitmap()
#root.minsize(width=1370, height=800)
#root.maxsize(width=1370, height=800)

background = PhotoImage(file="background.jpeg")
background_label = Label(root,image=background)
background_label.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

However, when I run this code this error pops up:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4061, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4006, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "background.jpeg"
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: This might be something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357090/tkinter-error-couldnt-recognize-data-in-image-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter error: Couldn't recognize data in image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357090/tkinter-error-couldnt-recognize-data-in-image-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can Use ImageTk:

```
from PIL import ImageTk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("")
root.iconbitmap()

background = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="background.jpeg")
background_label = Label(root,image=background)
background_label.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Hope It Helps :D